# Issue with reading stored array from UserDefaults in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to add `Int` to an empty `Array` and then store its data with `UserDefaults` and then read it
 , Here is what I am doing :

```
//create an empty array
var intArray = [Int]()


func addToBookMark(Number:Int) {

    //Add object to array and save it
    intArray.append(Number)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(intArray, forKey: "bookmark")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


    //Read it
    let array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "bookmark")  as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
    print(array.description)

}

//Calling the method :
addToBookMark(Number: 30)
```

The problem is compiler gives me an empty array: `[]` What is my problem ?

Comment: Are you checking in simulator or playground?

Comment: @SivajeeBattina playground

Comment: The code you have written won't work in simulator or playground. Check in device. The syntax to store/get array from user defaults changed from swift 3.0

Comment: If you want it to work in simulator and playground also, you need to archieve the array using NSKeyedArchiver and store it.

Comment: your code is fine and correct

Comment: @SivajeeBattina there is no need of Archive, its already coding compliant.

Comment: I'm talking about the back compatibility as storing array only availble from swift 3.0. If you want to do it in objective C- or swift previous versions you need to archieve it and store it. Let me know If I'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is perfect, its the issue of simulators. So better try rebooting your Mac.

> WWDC Seed: Running multiple iOS simulators can cause NSUserDefaults to
>   not work
>
> Running an iOS 8 or 9 simulator followed by an iOS 10 simulator will
>   cause NSUserDefaults to stop working in the simulator. This can be
>   worked around by rebooting the host Mac.

In case of Playground , there is a [radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/26942432) regarding it as it not works on it since playground doesn't have access to sandbox.